# dnsmasq doesn't handle default DNS for unqualified names as expected

Tags: dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup DoH for all hostnames except some local domains that should be resolved by DNS provided by DHCP.

It works with fully-qualified names as expected, that is, local names are sent to DHCP assigned server and everything else is sent to my DoH client `stubby`. However, I'm having issues with handling of unqualified names.

Here is my configuration `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/example.conf`:

```
cache-size=1000
log-queries
server=//#
server=/example.com/#
server=/#/127.0.0.1#8053
```

Note that `stubby` is running on port 8053. For brevity, here is my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Here is a part of `journalctl` output after restartng `NetworkManager`:

```
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#8053 for default
dnsmasq[10692]: using standard nameservers for domain example.com
dnsmasq[10692]: using standard nameservers for unqualified names    <<< NOTICE THIS
dnsmasq[10692]: cleared cache
dnsmasq[10692]: setting upstream servers from DBus
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#8053 for default
dnsmasq[10692]: using standard nameservers for domain example.com
dnsmasq[10692]: using standard nameservers for unqualified names
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 10.X.X.X#53(via enp0s31f6)
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 10.X.X.X#53 for domain example.com
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 10.X.X.X#53 for domain X.X.X.10.in-addr.arpa
dnsmasq[10692]: using nameserver 10.X.X.X#53 for domain X.X.X.10.in-addr.arpa
```

After `dig asdfg.com`, I get this:

```
dnsmasq[10692]: query[A] asdfg.com from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[10692]: forwarded asdfg.com to 127.0.0.1
```

So, DoH works as expected.

After `dig asdfg.example.com`, I get this:

```
dnsmasq[10692]: query[A] asdfg.example.com from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[10692]: forwarded asdfg.example.com to 10.X.X.X
```

So, forwarding to local DNS also works.

After `dig asdfg`, I get this:

```
dnsmasq[10692]: query[A] asdfg from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[10692]: forwarded asdfg to 127.0.0.1
```

Since it sends it to `127.0.0.1` instead of `10.X.X.X`, it's clear it is sent to DoH.

How can I fix this?

ps. Debian 11, Dnsmasq version 2.85

Comment: Normally your DHCP server would send `example.com` as a domain suffix for the client resolver to add before it sent its query to your DNS server

Comment: @roaima ~This is related to the format of packet IIUC.~ Nevermind this part. But the question is still same: Why does it send it to the default server (=127.0.0.1#8053) instead of "standard nameservers" (=10.X.X.X#53) as it was logged?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a bug [[1](https://www.mail-archive.com/dnsmasq-discuss@lists.thekelleys.org.uk/msg15291.html), [2](https://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=commit;h=58cf958e416f3fe309a2abc1a84fd0a0ba302432)] fixed with version 2.86.